# Normal to a parabola

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If we have to find normal to the $x^2 = 4by$

I tried

Let a point be $(-2bm,bm^2)$

Then equation of tangents is

$-2bmx = 2b(y + bm^2)$        hence slope is $-2m$

So the slope of normal is $1/(2m)$ and equation is

$Y-bm^2 = (\frac{1}{2}m) ( x + 2bm)$

But this is not correct

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you were asked to find the normal at the point $(-2bm,bm^2)$.

From $x^2=4by$ we find that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{4b}$. When $x=-2bm$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-m$.

So the slope of the normal, if $m\ne 0$, is $\frac{1}{m}$.

The normal therefore has equation $y-bm^2=\frac{1}{m}\left(x+2bm\right)$. You may be expected to give a "simplified" form, such as $y=\frac{x}{m}+2b+bm^2$.